# Webapi POST works, but not DELETE

Tags: c#, json, http, rest, asp.net-web-api

My web application sends a POST or a DELETE HTTP request to my web api project. The POST works well, but the DELETE throws the following http 500 error:

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'EasNotification' from content with media type'text/plain'.",
"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace":" at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteBindingAsync>b__0(HttpParameterBinding parameterBinder)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.IterateImpl(IEnumerator`1 enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
```

Both POST and DELETE have the following in their header:

> Accept:application/json, text/plain,

The Hook object being posted and deleted are both the same JSON object.

I'd like to understand why does the DELETE throw the exception ?

Here is my controller methods:

```
 public void DeleteHook(Hook hook)
 {
      try
      {
           var hookRepo = new HookRepository();  <--- Breakpoint never reached
           hookRepo.DeleteNotificationHook(hook);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           var httpStatus = statusBuilder.GetStatusCode(ex.GetType());
           var httpError = new HttpError(ex, true);
           var errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(httpStatus, httpError);
           throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
      }
 }

 public void PostHook(Hook hook)
 {
      try
      {
           var hookRepo = new HookRepository();
           hookRepo.UpsertHook(hook);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           var httpStatus = statusBuilder.GetStatusCode(ex.GetType());
           var httpError = new HttpError(ex, true);
           var errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(httpStatus, httpError);
           throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Are you actually passing a Hook object back from the view? Generally a Delete controller method just takes an ID value.

Comment: I pass a full object. I will try reimplementing with an id in the url instead, but it on clear wether what I'm trying to do is or is not or should be supported.

Comment: Passing the full object might be a problem as normally DELETE is much like a GET and has no content. Having Fiddler running can be helpful as well.

Comment: I switched to an Id based strategy and it worked. I am still wondering why the other way isnt supported tho ...

Comment: Did you try to include the content-length header together with the body? Haven't tried this with webapi but in general, http delete can contain nonempty body.